# Rails, calling model method from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A little new to Rails, but simply, I have a model method that calculates the date difference:

```
def days_diff
  (end_date.to_date - start_date.to_date).to_i + 1
end
```

I want to be able to use this value/method in my controller to loop a form field x number of times. How do I about calling this method from the controller to use this variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what model is it in?

Comment: I would suggest to first have rails fundamentals clear. Recommend http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

Say your model is named ModelName. In your controller method you would have:

```
def controller_method
  @model_name = ModelName.find(params[:id]) # or however you obtain your model
  x = @model_name.days_diff
  x.times do |index|
    # call your loop stuff here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the method in your model as

```
self.days_diff
```

and then call it in the controller as

```
model_name.days_diff
```